# Using extern in C++ to share vairables

Tags: c++, arduino, extern

I have looked online at using extern with examples however when I have applied it to my project it either says that the variable has been defined multiple times within the project or the variable is out of scope

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SimPre.h>

void setup() {
  example();
  simController.println("Test");
}

void loop() {
  example();
}
```

**SimPre.h**

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

#ifndef SIM_PRE
#define SIM_PRE

extern SoftwareSerial simController(7, 8);

void example();

#endif
```

**SimPre.cpp**

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "SimPre.h"

void example() {
  simController.println("Test");
}
```

The above code shows me trying to access the simController variable from the main.c and it should also be accessible from SimPre.c however I get an error:

```
libraries/SimPre/SimPre.cpp.o:(.bss.simController+0x0): multiple definition of `simController'
sketch/DilshadSIM.ino.cpp.o:(.bss.simController+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: This is not [tag:c], so the answer depends on that! Is it [tag:c++], I still can't understand what programming language is used in arduino! But it's certainly not [tag:c].

Comment: You have tagged this question as `c` and mentioned `.c` files, but the error messages clearly show C++ extensions. Are you really *sure* you're not working with C++? Because if you do, it's really relevant.

Comment: Sorry they're CPP files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SimPre.h declare it as:

```
extern SoftwareSerial simController;
```

Comment: Thats perfect thanks! Now everything seems to be working